# Making 3D with Java ? DLP Link glasses

Tags: java, 3d

For a school project, we have DLP Link glasses with an Acer projector, and we would like to develop a demonstration application in Java, showing some 3D features.. Unfortunately, I can't find good resources on how to make it, and I'm wondering if you have some ideas ?

How do I link my application to these glasses ? How can I develop easily something in Java, that will allow me to actually display 3D ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the graphics card in the system that your code runs on supports 3D output, all you need to do is use the standard OpenGL or DirectX 3D functions and the graphics card should do the rest. You probably won't have to worry at all about whether your graphics card outputs things on a 3D projector, 2D regular monitor, or which type of glasses it uses...

For that, you can start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_OpenGL

Comment: Are you sure it would be automatic ? Because I thing you can make 3D in Java, but not actually render it as 3D (I am thinking of programs without glasses) ; I would do some tests, but it seems weird to me that we can make it without anything :/

Comment: I don't think it's automatic, but if you're using OpenGL or Direct3D, you are basically giving the GFX-card all data as a 3D image anyways. Cards that support it (like most nvidia cards) should then give you a driver setting somewhere to render the image as 3D on a respective display (see first paragraph here: http://www.nvidia.com/object/3d-vision-games.html - basically: it does 3D on most games that weren't written to support it). To be able to render the seperate images yourself, you actually need a professional card: http://www.nvidia.com/object/quadro_stereo_technology.html